# Change value depending on choices made in menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make work my price estimator using jQuery and some basic javascript functions.

What I want to do is to change to value of my `total` variable, depending on the choices made in the dropdown menus. My prices aren't made from a unit price, so I need to set a price for a set of options. You'll understand by seeing my JS code (what I tried that is not working)

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72Jbe/).

And here's my JS code :

```
var total=0;
$('#total span').text(total);


if  (document.getElementById("paperSelect").value == "14 PT 1" && document.getElementById("printedSelect").value == "Front Only" && document.getElementById("quantitySelect").value == "500" && document.getElementById("turnaroundSelect").value == "4 days")
{
total=150; 
}
```

Here's my HTML code :

```
   <form id="calculator">

    <center>
      <label class="titleLabels">Business cards</label></center>

     <label class="formLabels">Dimensions :</label>
    <select id="sizeSelect" class="formSelects">
      <option value="3.5x2">3.5&quot; x 2&quot;</option>
      <option value="3.5x1.25">3.5&quot; x 1.25&quot;</option>
    </select>

    <label class="formLabels">Paper :</label>
    <select id="paperSelect" class="formSelects">
        <option value="14 PT 1" selected="selected">14 PT Cardstock Gloss</option>
        <option value="14 PT 2">14 PT Cardstock Matte</option>
    </select>

    <label class="formLabels">Printed :</label>
    <select id="printedSelect" class="formSelects">
        <option value="Front Only" selected="selected">Front Only</option>
        <option value="Front and Back">Front and Back</option>
    </select>

    <label class="formLabels">Quantity :</label>
    <select id="quantitySelect" class="formSelects">
            <option value="250">250</option>
            <option value="500" selected="selected">500</option>
    </select>

    <label class="formLabels">Production :</label>
    <select id="turnaroundSelect" class="formSelects">
        <option value="5 days" selected="selected">5 days</option>
        <option value="4 days">4 days</option>
    </select>

    <div id="totalBox">
        <label class="formLabels" id="total"> Total : $<span></span></label>
    </div>


<!-- hidden values -->    
    <input type="hidden" id="sizeSelect_value" value="50" name="formValues" />
    <input type="hidden" id="paperSelect_value" value="20" name="formValues" />
    <input type="hidden" id="printedSelect_value" value="0" name="formValues" />
    <input type="hidden" id="quantitySelect_value" value="25" name="formValues" />
    <input type="hidden" id="turnaroundSelect_value" value="5" name="formValues" />

    </form>​
​
```

Comment: Well they are no "logic" prices matrix, if I can explain myself that way. I decide the prices by comparing to the competition. So it is pretty random. But the way I create the prices depend on the choices in the dropdown menus. Like what I tried to do in my JS code

Comment: can't help if everything is random... you have to have some sort of matrix, or way to figure out relationship between various selections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/72Jbe/3/

Here's the revised Javascript:

```
var total=0;
$('#total span').text(total);

$('form').on('change', 'select', function() { 
    if  (document.getElementById("paperSelect").value == "14 PT 1" && document.getElementById("printedSelect").value == "0" && document.getElementById("quantitySelect").value == "30" && document.getElementById("turnaroundSelect").value == "15")
{
    total=150; 
    $('#total span').text(total);
}

});
```

First problem is that you were matching agains the text descriptions, not against the values for the second, third and fourth parts of the if statement.

Second problem was that you need to attach this to the change event for the select tags.

Third problem is that you weren't saving the new total after it changed.

Run the fiddle, and change the bottom value to 4 days and it will work.​

Comment: Thank you for telling me what wasn't working. Now I understand better what was the problems. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You must actually change the line

```
<option value="14 PT 2">14 PT Cardstock Matte</option>
```

to

```
<option value="14 PT 2" selected="selected">14 PT Cardstock Matte</option>
```

And not just change the "value" of the Select.

You could do with:

```
$("#paperSelect option[selected=selected]").removeAttr("selected") ;
$("#paperSelect option[value=" + value + "]").attr("selected","selected") ;
```

edit: Just making things prettier